# What is point of /: function?

Tags: scala

Documentation for `/:` includes

```
  Note: might return different results for different runs, unless the underlying collection type is ordered or the operator
   is associative and commutative.
```

( [src](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@/:[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B))

This just applies if the par version of this function is run, otherwise the result is deterministic (same as foldLeft) ?

Also this function is calling foldLeft under the hood  : `def /:[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = foldLeft(z)(op)`

Their function definitions are same (except for function param label, "op" instad of "f") :

```
  def /:[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
  def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

For these reasons what is point of `/:` function and when should it be used in favour of foldLeft ? 
  Is my reasoning incorrect ?

Comment: They are the same. The `:\ ` is the pair of `foldRight`. Probably the symbolic names were first and then come the alphabetical. The advantage of `/:` is that it is right associative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Yes, those are aliases originating from dark times when people liked their operators like this:
`val x = y |@<@|: z`.*

The point of the note is to remind that for collections with unspecified iteration order the result of `fold`s might differ. Consider having a `Set {1,2,3}` that doesn't guarantee the same access order even if left unmodified, and applying an operation that is not e. g. associative (like `/`). Even if run not after `par` call, this might result in the following (pseudocode):

1. `{1,2,3} foldLeft / ==> (1 / 2) / 3 ==> 1/6 = 0.1(6)`
2. `{3,1,2} foldLeft / ==> (3 / 1) / 2 ==> 3/2 = 1.5`

In terms of consistency this is similar to applying non-parallelizable operations to parallel collections, though.

Answer (score 3):

It's just an alternative syntax. Methods ending in `:` are called on the *right* hand side.

Instead of

```
list.foldLeft(0) { op(_, _) }
```

or

```
list./:(0) { op(_, _) }
```

you can

```
( z /: list ) { op(_, _) }
```

For example,

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> ( 0 /: a ) { _ + _ }
res5: Int = 10
```